# Xamarin Forms Navigation inside Frame

Tags: xamarin.forms

Coming from UWP's development, i wondering is it is possible to have navigation inside a Frame in Xamarin Forms. I saw on documentation Frame element have INavigation property, so i tried this code :

```
MyFrame.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
```

But when i'm trying to execute this code on Android, i get the following error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'PushAsync is not supported globally
> on Android, please use a NavigationPage.'

But when i do this :

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

The navigation does not work as expected because it is global and not inside the Frame. We have to have a global navigation or it is impossible to have a specific navigation ? The goal is to have a static part in the app and a part where navigation takes place.

For example, with Uno Platform we can use UWP Frame and perform navigation inside it, so i wondering why it is not possible in Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could define a property with type of  **INavigation** in a custom Frame

```
public class MyFrame:Frame
{
    public INavigation CurrentNavigation { get; private set; }

    public MyFrame (INavigation navigation)
    {
        CurrentNavigation = navigation;
    }

}
```

#### in MainPage

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame(this.Navigation);
        myFrame.CurrentNavigation.PushAsync(new Page1());

    }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for quick answer. But then, where do i declare my navigationpage so that the navigation can be performed inside the Frame and not globally ?

Comment: It is necessary to set the MainPage as NavigationPage .

Comment: Ok so it is not possible to accomplish what i want in Xamarin Forms :/ I will mark your response as answer , it made me realize that my request was unachievable.